# What is actually involved in a mvp scenario to use google guice?

Tags: java, guice

I am very familiar with using spring to inject using @Bean & @Autowired.  I have switched over to looking at guice and I am wondering what is the minimum involved to have it functioning.  The following basic example throws a NPE:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ClassA {

    String a = "test";

    @Inject
    public ClassA() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public void go() {
        System.out.println("two");
    }
}
```

The following class attempting to instantiate a new instance of ClassA:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ClassB {

    @Inject
    ClassA guice;

    public ClassB() {
        guice.go();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
    }

}
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations of the following with no success:

```
public class SupportModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(ClassA.class);
        //bind(ClassA.class).to(ClassB.class);
        //others too

    }
}
```

I must be missing a key thing somewhere here, I'm not quite sure where? do I need some manual instantiation of guice/configuration itself? I assume I possibly do.

`guice.go();` <= NullPointerException occurs here, obviously the obj is null because my guice setup isn't right

In Spring i can do the following, I assume Guice can aid me in doing this too:

```
@Bean
public FrameworkProperties properties() {
    return new FrameworkProperties();
}
```

and then just:

```
@Autowired
FrameworkProperties props;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need some manual instantiation of guice/configuration itself? I assume I possibly do.

Yes, you assumed right. You'll have to bootstrap the Injector modules that you have defined using the `Guice.createInjector()` method. Also, one other thing to note is when using a custom defined constructor like in ClassB, you'll have to use constructor injection. So in order to get this working, ClassB should look like:

```
public class ClassB {

    private ClassA guice;

    @Inject //This will inject the dependencies used in the constructor arguments
    public ClassB(final ClassA guice) {
        this.guice = guice;
        guice.go();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /**
         * If only type to type binding is required, you can skip creating a Module class &
         * bootstrap the injector with empty argument createInjector like used below. But, when
         * there are other kind of bindings like Type to Implementations defined in modules, you can use:
         * final Injector injector1 = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule1(), new GuiceModule2());
         */
        final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector();
        final ClassB b = injector.getInstance(ClassB.class); //This will create dependency graph for you and inject all dependencies used by ClassB and downwards
    }
}
```

Also, you can remove the @Inject annotation used in ClassA's constructor as you are not injecting any external dependencies in that constructor. You can look up the Guice's getting started [wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted) for more documentation.

Comment: say I wanted to have a simple object A as an instance variable in Object B, what is required there? Do i need to keep referencing and typing the injector code? and what if my application doesn't have a main method?

Comment: If not used in the constructor, use field injection. This would be identical to spring, just replace `@Autowired` with `@Inject`

Comment: but I need then somewhere to setup the injector etc? I don't have a main method in my automation framework and I don't want to type the injector code in every class that uses it for example?

Comment: You only have to bootstrap it once. If no main method, what about configuration methods in the test like `@BeforeSuite` or `@BeforeClass`  which will run once and at the beginning of test execution.

Comment: Im going to try bootstrap once using my listener which runs when the test execution cycle starts, investigating that now :)